# Half overlap two symbols from amssymb

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols, combine

I am using the empty and filled triangle `amssymb` but i need a third one. It should look like the `\blacktriangleright` in the first half and like `\rhd` in the second half.

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

$\rhd$

$\blacktriangleright$

% half \blacktriangleright and half \rhd

\end{document}
```

---

**Desired output** made in paint:

[image: half black half white triangle]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution, which composes the symbol with a clipped version of `\blacktriangleright` and the full symbol `\rhd`.
The example uses `\mathrel` for the result as relational symbol (like `\blacktriangleright`). If the final symbol should be better a binary symbol (like `\rhd`), then `\mathrel` needs to be replaced by `\mathbin`. Luckily 
both symbols of package `amssymb` match in form and dimension of the triangle and in the character widths including side bearings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{trimclip}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\halfblacktriangleright}{}%
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\halfblacktriangleright}{%
  \mathrel{% like \blacktriangleright or \mathbin like \rhd
    \mathpalette\@halfblacktriangleright{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@halfblacktriangleright}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \rlap{%
    \clipbox{0 0 {.55\width} 0}{$#1\blacktriangleright\m@th$}%
  }%
  \rhd
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%$\rhd\quad\blacktriangleright$

$1\halfblacktriangleright 2\quad
\scriptstyle 1\halfblacktriangleright 2\quad
\scriptscriptstyle 1\halfblacktriangleright 2$

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Definition variation which uses `\@ifdefinable` for checking, whether a macro is already defined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{trimclip}
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{\halfblacktriangleright}{%
  \@ifdefinable{\@halfblacktriangleright}{%
    \protected\def\halfblacktriangleright{%
      \mathrel{% like \blacktriangleright or \mathbin like \rhd
        \mathpalette\@halfblacktriangleright{}%
      }%
    }%
    \def\@halfblacktriangleright#1#2{%
      % #1: math style
      % #2: unused
      \rlap{%
        \clipbox{0 0 {.55\width} 0}{$#1\blacktriangleright\m@th$}%
      }%
      \rhd%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%$\rhd\quad\blacktriangleright$

$1\halfblacktriangleright 2\quad
\scriptstyle 1\halfblacktriangleright 2\quad
\scriptscriptstyle 1\halfblacktriangleright 2$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! I didnt know about the `trimclip` package before.  Perhaps `\newcommand` should be `\DeclareRobustCommand`, because `\rlap` is not expandable (as `\clipbox` probably).  Thus using `\halfblacktriangleright` will currently lead to nice surprises when used in section headings.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks, the updated answer makes it robust and fixes a smaller issue with the number of arguments for `\@halfblacktriangleright`.

Comment: Now I have a question.  Why the empty `\newcommand*{\halfblacktriangleright}{}`? Does `\newcommand` do some extra bookkeeping which `\DeclareRobustCommand` is lacking?  And one “optimization” egreg once suggested:  use `\relax` instead of `{}` as the second argument to `\mathpalette` — it saves you one token!

Comment: @HenriMenke The additional `\newcommand` checks, whether the macro is already defined. I have appended a version, which instead uses `\@ifdefinable` and e-TeX's `\protected`.

Comment: @HenriMenke On the other hand `\relax` as "empty" argument is not empty, but is one token instead of no tokens. Also `\relax` is longer to write and less clear to read than `{}` for an empty argument.