# DLL for convert latex equation to image

Tags: equations, windows

I need to convert a latex equation to image format. The better if i can find a DLL  (i found a mention of such possibility here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137105/delphi-component-or-library-to-display-mathematical-expressions/10140214 but can not find DLL)  that take a latex equation string and return any image format. If it not possible what is a minimum set of files that can do such task, the TeX distributive is large enough, the conversion need only for equations.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [LaTeXIt](https://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-features.php) ?

Comment: Only part that convert latex to image format, no other. The better if they will have a smaller size as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to move your equation into a separate file, you can use the tools provided by your TeX distribution and need nothing else.  I assume you're using TeXlive.

First, you need a file containing your equation with no page numbers, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}  
\Huge
\begin{equation*}
  a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Run `pdflatex` on this file (say, `temp.tex`).

Next, run `pdfcrop` on the generated `temp.pdf` getting `temp-crop.pdf`.

Last, run `ghostscript` on `temp-crop.pdf` to generate an image file.  `ghostscript` is shipped with TeXlive and the binary is called `rungs`.  A sample invocation can be like this:

```
rungs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4
-sDEVICE=png256 -r600x600 -sOutputFile=temp.png temp-crop.pdf
```

Check this link for [usage options](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.20/Use.htm) and this one for [devices/formats](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.20/Devices.htm).

Comment: The TeX distribution is very large. I need a simple and rather small solution, like a http://latex2png.com/ but in DLL and in-memory transform without using files.

Answer (score 0):

There are lighter TeX distributions, and you could probably strip those down further.  Or MikTeX can install packages as required, meaning you could start with a minimum installation.  These would still all use an executable with file I/O rather than calling a function in a DLL, because TeX works in a Unix-style way, where passing through files is the norm. It also was developed for systems with very little memory.

Defining the minimum set of files required isn't simple -- it depends what you need in your equations.  Do you, for example, need [blackboard bold numerals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44283/28808), or [triangle symbols, and the ability to combine them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320116/28808).  Both of these arbitrary examples would require the ability to add `\usepackage` to the preamble. You could dump all of the classes except standalone, many of the fonts, TikZ (probably) etc. and save a lot of disk space, but disk space is cheap.